# How do I authorize this with CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a method that looks like the following in my controller:

```
 def some_request
    user = User.find(params[:friend_user_id])
    req = user.requests.build(:from_id => current_user.id)
    # do more stuff!
 end
```

Now this is in a controller called `RandomController` for arguments sake. This is both a RESTful controller with nonRESTful methods as depicted below. I'm only using `authorize_resource` and no loading of resources. I thought I'd be able to manage this by doing the following in my Ability class:

```
  class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user
      can :manage, Request do |req|
        req.user_id == user.id
      end
    end
  end
```

This isn't doing it. How do I modify some_request to authorize the creation of a Request? Basically I want to do the following: Allow any authenticated user to perform all CRUD operations (:manage) on a Request that belongs to them and them only. User has a relationship of `has_many` with Request as in:

```
has_many :requests
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. you're calling `req.user.id`, which may not be loading the user resource (and probably shouldn't, either!). Change that to `req.user_id` and save yourself the request of the user resource.
2. CanCan requires you use the `current_user` object, not just `user`.

Ryan Bates has done a fantastic job of documenting the features and capabilities of CanCan. Have a look at the [RailsCast #192 episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) (or the [plain-text ASCII-cast version](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)) and the [GitHub project](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for more details.

Comment: Point 1 makes sense. 2 does not. In my Ability class, the initialize method looks like this:  def initialize(user), and that is essentially current_user. This doesn't really answer the original question.

Comment: @randombits, Chris can't see the rest of your Ability class so in the context of what is visible his second point does make sense.